# Object.entries() duplica os valores do enum na hora de fazer um map

Tags: react, typescript, next.js

Estou usando React com Next e TypeScript e preciso fazer gerar um select com algumas espécies de animais, porém na hora de fazer o `map` para gerar as `option`'s o compilador duplica os valores.

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte enum (prefiro que comece com o índice 1), que uso o seguinte `map` para gerar os `option`'s:

```
enum Animal {
  Cat     = 1,
  Dog     = 2,
  Hamster = 3
}

const getAnimalOptions = () =>
  Object.entries(Animal).map(([ value, key ]) => <option value={key}>{value}</option>)
```

Porém esse código me gera algo nesse sentido:

```
<option value=1       > Cat     </option>
<option value=2       > Dog     </option>
<option value=3       > Hamster </option>
<option value=Cat     > 1       </option>
<option value=Dog     > 2       </option>
<option value=Hamster > 3       </option>
```

Como podem ver, os valores do enum são duplicados de forma invertida. Eu acho que consegui contornar a situação mudando o número de cada enum para string, tipo assim:

```
enum Animal {
  Cat     = '1',
  Dog     = '2',
  Hamster = '3'
}
```

Dessa forma não duplica, porém acho meio feio (e não estou certo se é o correto).
Outra solução que encontrei foi fazer um `for .. of` e sinalizar um `break` point:

```
const getAnimalOptions = () => {
  const options: any = [];
  const allAnimals = Object.entries(Animal);

  for (const [ idx, animal ] of allAnimals) {
    if (!isNaN(+animal))
      break;
    
    const option = <option value={idx}>{animal}</option>;
    options.push(option);
  }

  return options;
}
```

Está funcionando, mas não sei se é manutenível, além de que me incomoda trocar as duas linhas do `map` com arrow function por essas várias linhas do `for .. of`. rs

Sendo assim, alguém tem alguma solução melhor, por favor?

Comment: Em vez de `enum`, use um objeto simples:  `const Animal = { Cat: 1, Dog: 2, Hamster: 3 }` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums

Comment: @hkotsubo meu caro, obrigado pela sugestão. Não conhecia essa sintaxe de `as const` e pelo meu teste aqui já resolveu a questão de usar o `map`.

Comment: Única “perda” aparente é que o `enum` me permite fazer assim { Cat = 1, Dog, Hamster }, onde numerar apenas a 1ª opção ele já numera as demais para mim. Mas enfim está tudo bem.